# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer creating 2 views when resizing

Tags: ios, swift, view, autoresizingmask

I have made a Camera object that I am attaching on a CameraViewController. The Camera object has the following method inside, which sets the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` on a given view controller.

```
func displayPreview(on view: UIView) throws {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
            throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer!, at: 0)
        previewLayer?.frame = view.bounds
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        previewLayer?.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

In the CameraViewController, to set the camera  object, I am doing the following

```
var camera = Camera()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
    }


    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        try? self.camera.displayPreview(on: self.view)
    }


    private func configureView(){
        self.view.addTapGestureRecognizer(action: {
            if let parentView = self.parent?.view.frame{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
                    self.view.layer.borderWidth = 0
                    self.view.frame = parentView
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

It all works well, to the point the view is resizing. When this happens, it looks like the camera is creating 2 views, like in the picture, an older one on the top and an updated one view's size. Not only that, but when the view resizes, it looks like the previewLayer reloads before resizing (it takes a bit before the bigger view appears). What I am trying to achieve is a continuous animated camera preview resize view. What do I need to change in my code? I've been playing with placing `try? self.camera.displayPreview(on: self.view)` in different view load parts, but that did not change anything.

[image]

Comment: try to move try? self.camera.displayPreview(on: self.view) into viewDidAppear method

Comment: @NazarLisovyi yes, originally it was like this, but it doesn't work

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubviews will be called multiple times on each resize or orientation change. Introduce some check in your displayPreview method to avoid adding the preview layer again and again. Change its frame instead to adjust the resizing.

Comment: @HAK you know, I was actually wondering what's up with that smaller outdated view. If I debug it in view mode, it shows it as one window/frame, and not as 2 views

Comment: @dre_84w934it doesn't work at all??

Comment: I mean it didn't do what I wanted to. It does the same